# Rotate camera around 3D cube with gyroscope

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, camera, jpct

I need to develop app demo that shows camera preview and as overlay render 3D model. When user rotate device, the camera that is looking at the object should rotate as well. My knowledge about 3D is pretty basic. I have used jPCT-AE engine for this but I have problem that the camera in its world is moving a little bit different than camera from the real world. Do you know, how I can achieve this same effect only with openGL? Or any other 3D engine that could help me.. OpenGL is very low-level that i dont want to dive into if its not completely necesasry. Thanks

Comment: If you look in the Examples in the Android SDK you should find a demo called `RotationVectorDemo` that you might be interested in.

Comment: @beaker thanks, i know this demo but it is rotating the model and not the camera that is looking at it.

Comment: Well, if you think about it, there's no difference between rotating a model about its center and rotating the camera around the model in the opposite direction.